# Create settings for android program

Tags: android

At the current moment, I am creating program and now I need create the settings of the program. There are approximately 12 different settings for my program and I divided into 3 groups:

- 1 group has textview + edittext
- 2 group has textview + button
- 3 group starts a fragment

I am thinking how create this settings? Create a special layout with scroll or may be try listview (recyclerview)? Or are there any other variants?

Comment: Preference Screen is the most common way..check the link for more details.. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[PreferenceActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)** to build a settings activity

http://alvinalexander.com/android/android-tutorial-preferencescreen-preferenceactivity-preferencefragment

Comment: Thank's for the example!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ScrollView with LinearLayout.

Comment: It's good posibility, but I am looking for more common way. Thank you